# Where is the windows terminal settings location?

Tags: windows-terminal

I edited the settings file and there must have been a typo and now the app crashes on startup.

Online the documentation says the settings lives in `$env:LocalAppData\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json`

I can't figure out what that path means since it doesn't exist on the computer.

Comment: By the way, `$env:LocalAppData` is the way Powershell refers to environment variables. In CMD the equivalent would be `%LocalAppData%`. Moreover, the CMD version is accepted by File Explorer, so you could just paste `%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState` in the address bar and it would open the folder.

Comment: what a shitty programming solution... this file should be in the same older as the program (the general... ot the only ~99% use cases)... and for the ~1% specific cases in the %USREPROFILE%/$home .terminal.json file...

Answer (score 48):

I re-installed the app to fix the problem then made sure to see what the actual path is.

It's located in : `C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState`

Comment: What an ugly directory name!

Comment: I just made [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74042682/4575793) out of  @user1340531
's great comment

Answer (score 16):

In the current version (1.7.1033.0), the application can open the JSON settings file for you via a button. Open the Settings tab, and the bottom left corner will have a button named "Open JSON file". Clicking that button will open a prompt asking with what application to open the file. That text editor can then tell you where the file is located.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Stupid question: how do you open the settings tab? I can open the file directly with Ctrl+Alt+, (i.e. Ctrl+Alt+comma). Ok, I found it: it's Ctrl+, (i.e. Ctrl+comma) to open GUI version of the settings.

Comment: @Fizz Based on my screenshot: you click the little down-arrow-button next to the + button when creating a new tab. Settings is available as a choice in addition to the different terminals.

Comment: There is no arrow on my powershell executed as admin. Would you know where that could come from ?

Comment: For me it looks the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/66003513/4462442

Answer (score 7):

If you open the terminal settings, it will open a text editor with the settings.json file. If your default editor is VS Code it will show you the path below the tabs on the top of the screen.

[image: Settings menu in Windows Terminal]

I'm unsure what other editors show you the path, but if it is crucial you can change your default text editor to Code.

Comment: No, it will not "open a text editor" - in my case it opens damned Visual Studio, whose "community" license expired and Microsoft wants me to Log in and "refresh" the "community" license - like hell I will! Good to know after all it is just a file, so I can open it in something else.

Comment: In this case OP specifically states they're unable to launch the program because the settings are invalid, so this doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are running Windows Terminal through the .zip folder download, the settings file will be located in:

> C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Terminal

Comment: This is also the file for the scoop version (not the one in the actual `~\scoop`)

Answer (score 1):

There is still the option to open the JSON file through settings. In version 1.15.2875.0 you can still find the "Open JSON file" at the bottom left corner

[Screenshot with highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRdSr.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This hint was given by a comment by [user1340531](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340531/user1340531):

> Mine is at `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\settings.json`

(or more generically: `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\settings.json`)

---

If it's not there, you should consider [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2532762/1mike12) or [vyps comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63101571/where-is-the-windows-terminal-settings-location#comment116077224_63101571) which lets you find out one of these generic paths (they are equivalent):

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState
             %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState
          $env:LocalAppData\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState
```

---

If you don't know what these paths mean, I'd recommend playing around with "Windows Run" (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and the explorer address bar.